# How do i resolve Information Exposure Through an Error Message to remove all the e.printstacktrace and log the error as custom message?

Tags: java, security, coding-style, standards

Information Exposure Through an Error Message 
`try{ } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();}`
How can we design custom logger to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the printStackTrace with something like:

```
Logger.getLogger(<your-class>.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

Comment: Logger will also exposed information or it will resolved the above problem.

Comment: @VISHALKUMAR yes, because you can configure what is being written to the log. A more radical approach would be to remove all the logging, of course.

Comment: @Maurice_Perry Yes, Got it better to remove all the e.printstacktrace and add custom log with standard name as tag value.